# Getting java.lang.NumberFormatException when trying to convert string to ascii

Tags: scala, ascii

I am trying to convert a string to its ascii equivalent using ".toInt", and I am repeatedly getting this error:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "'_'"
  java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:67)
  java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:654)
```

This is the line it is failing at:

```
P.map[Expression]{ case y => Chrc(y.toInt)}
```

Chrc is a parser that returns a string.

I have tried just doing

```
val x = '_'
println(x.toInt)
```

outside the block of code I am writing in and it works, so the issue is to do with this sentence and the fact that i am trying to change it to an integer inside the Chrc class. Is there another way to write this?

Comment: You've got a string that contains two simple quotes around the underscore. Is that expected? It obviously cannot be converted to a int.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what you mean by "ASCII representation" but `"3".toInt` will give you `3` and not `51`.

Comment: @GaëlJ toInt should let you turn a character to its ASCII version. e.g. _ should be 95 and a should be 97. https://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/ascii-table.html

Comment: That was my point: it works on a **character**, not on a string.

Comment: the exception message says `For input string: "'_'"`, which means you have an String with the value `'_'`. You are applying `toInt` to that string value. You could get the ascii code of each character, `'`, `_` and `'` but not the ascii of `'_'`

Comment: the example you tried out of your code `val x = '_'` is converting the character `_` to the ascii value. Not sure how to fix your code because it's not a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), but you should check why you are trying to cast an string of 3 chars to an int

Answer (score 3):

The problem is reproducible as follows:

```
scala> val x = "'_'"
val x: String = '_'
                                                                                                    
scala> x.toInt
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "'_'"
  at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:67)
  at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:654)
  at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:786)
  at scala.collection.StringOps$.toInt$extension(StringOps.scala:908)
  ... 32 elided
```

Here, `x` is a `String`. That's different from the code you supplied:

```
scala> val x = '_'
val x: Char = _
                                                                                                    
scala> x.toInt
val res1: Int = 95
```

in which `x` is a `Char`.

It is a peculiarity of both Scala and Java that the `Char` type (in Java, `char` with a small `c`) is an integer type, and thus `toInt` is a numeric conversion giving you the ASCII value of the character, rather than parsing it.